# Local Eclipse plugin repo for a team

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, repository, mirror, ibm-rad

what would be a preferred solution for hosting a small local plugin repository with a couple of our own plugins?

- the team is using RAD7, which is Eclipse 3.2 based
- we cannot upgrade RAD to 7.5.5 yet, so all Ganymede/Galileo repo tools cannot be used, i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like eclipse.org, and zip the plugins.

With a small team, unzipping the plugins onto the local file system is sufficient.